# How to sort array by enum value

Tags: c#, sorting, enums

I have an array and one of its elements uses enum. 
I want to sort the array by enum.

```
public enum EnumList
    {
        Spring,
        Summer,
        Fall,
        Winter,
        Unknown
    };
```

My array looks like this:

```
 Class1[] arr = new class1[7];

        arr[0] = new class1(101, "Some string", Class1.EnumList.Spring, 100, DateTime.Parse("10/13/2008"));
 .
 .
 array continues..
```

How do I sort by enum value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [IEnumerable.OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8).

If you sort by an enum-value it will look at the underlying type (usually int) and sort by that. This means the best solution would just be like this:
`arr.OrderBy(c => c.TheEnumProperty);`

This method will return a sorted IEnumerable which you can cast back to an array with [IEnumerable.ToArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
var sortedByEnum = arr.GroupBy(x => x.enum).OrderBy(group => group);
```

Comment: You can indent the code by 4 spaces to have it formatted as code.

Comment: yes sorry, maybe you can make the edit request again